# Can I Union all tables (700+) and add new column with table name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this to help me generate code to union all 700 tables in my database. It works well

```
select 'select PartNumber, Quantity FROM '+TABLE_NAME +' union all'
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

However, I want to add a 3rd column that adds in the table name beside the relevant rows. Is there a way to this using the TABLE_NAME. I.e. so I don't have to manually add the table name for each one.

Comment: You'll need Dynamic SQL to achieve this.

Comment: Is this missing a `FROM`?

Comment: Dynamic sql? And how would that look in my case?

Comment: Sorry there should be a from after the word quantity before the quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the tablename in as a column:

```
select 'select PartNumber, Quantity, '''+TABLE_NAME +''' as table_name from ' + TABLE_NAME + ' union all' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

If your tables can have strange characters, you might need to take that into account.  Unfortunately, `QUOTENAME()` doesn't quite do what you need.  But `replace(table_name, '''', '''''')` will replace single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: I dont want to have to add 700+ table names manually. Is there a way around this or maybe I misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: Gordon - I made a tweak to your code and have it working

```select 'select PartNumber, Quantity, '''+TABLE_NAME +''' as table_name from '+TABLE_NAME+' union all' 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;```

Comment: @BarryMac . . . A `FROM` clause is very useful.

Comment: It is indeed. Thanks for the guidance